# Firebase notifications sent for android but not iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Flutter app, I am using a Firebase function to send the admin a notification every time a booking is made in the app, this is my code to push the message:

```
 //Function to initialise Notifications
  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    //request persmission from user
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

    generateDeviceToken();
//background
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
//foreground (The event is a Remote Message Arriving)
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) async {
      await NotificationApi.pushNotification(event);
    });

    //Here instead of passing to the onBackground message we will use notification package

    // Save the FCM token to the user's Firestore document
  }


Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
  if (message != null) {
    final title = message.data['title'];
    final body = message.data['body'];
    await NotificationApi.pushNotification(message);

    // Check if title and body are not null before using them
    if (title != null && body != null) {
      // print('Title: $title');
      // print('Body: $body');
      // print('Payload: ${message.data}');
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the notification API:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationApi {
  static final _notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void init() {
    _notification.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
      ),
    );
  }

  static pushNotification(
    RemoteMessage message,
  ) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channed id',
      'channel name',
      channelDescription: 'channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _notification.show(0, message.data['title'], message.data['body'],
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
}
```

It is showing invocations on the Firebase console but it is not showing notifications on iPhone or Android despite confirming notifications are on.

Here is my main:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await DBHandler().initNotification();
  NotificationApi.init();
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();

  runApp(ProviderScope(
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

It works just fine on an android phone but not on an iPhone I don't understand why?